# Raster layer divide

Tags: raster, export

I'm new to QGIS. I'm a Blender user and found that beautiful NZ height maps at koordinates.com which are CC 3.0 and free to use. I want to use these maps for height map displacement if I can export them correctly.

So I got these 32 tiff files from NZ and after I imported them and clicked on local histogram I can see my height maps for every separate layer.

My target is to merge these layers and then split them into 10-30 kilometer squares and save every part of these squares as a *.png with the highest possible resolution.

Is it possible to get more detail on the slope or terrain at all into Blender?

Where do I start? What should I read and think about?

Is it possible to safe the currently used Layer from OpenLayers too at the same time?